# Ionic3 / How can I do a navigation between two pages without go back on the first page

Tags: ionic3

When I do a navigation between two pages, I use this function:

```
goToOtherPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage);
  }
```

But on the OtherPage I have a buttom which permits me to come back on the first page..

So I would like to know please, how can I do a navigation between two pages without go back on the first page ?

Thanks in advance for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correctly:

By using `push` you add page on the stack so it will get back to the first page

there is another method which is called `setRoot` which loads a page and set it as first page, it means there is no back button and there is no page before that

`this.navCtrl.setRoot(OtherPage);`

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this method!!